# configuration MSSQL with PHP 5.6.x(xamp) using code-igniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have an issue while configuration `MSSQL DATABASE` with my codeigniter. I have placed these below file in `xamp/php/ext`:

1. `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`
2. `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`
3. `php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`
4. `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`

   I have also ensured to extended dll files in `php.ini`(I have tested both **ts** and **nts** separately)

**Below is my database file in codeigniter**

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'tcp:xyz.database.windows.net',
'username' => '****',
'password' => '****',
'database' => '****',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv', // i have use also mssql 
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**ERROR**

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/sqlsrv/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 436

I am using PHP Version 5.6.14 in XAMP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imho you should use a `dsn` for this - since you also installed the pdo driver you can try the following (1433 is the port - i don't know yours):

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlsrv:server=xyz.database.windows.net,1433;Database=****',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo', // i have use also mssql 
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: your update remove the previous ERROR with SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/sqlsrv/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php

Line Number: 142

Comment: Which port (1433) ?? client side or our localhost port

Comment: port = serverside where your db stands and yes you need the odbc driver

Comment: i haven't change the port . is this the issue or ODBC must be there . bec i hav odbc (how can assure that i have ODBC installed)

Comment: take a look @your link - install the odbc version and try it again